# Use chunk to insert data into database Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to separate tournament players into different groups. I am using the `chunk` method to separate players as a group for every 10 players(or users).

I am trying like below:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $tournamentid = $request->tournamentid;
    $data = TournamentPlayer::where('tournament_id', $tournamentid)->get()->chunk(10);

    for ($i=1; $i <= count($data); $i++) {
        foreach ($data as $group) {
            foreach ($group as $key => $value) {
                TournamentGroup::create([
                    'group' => $i,
                    'tournament_id' => $tournamentid,
                    'user_id' => $value->user_id //player
                ]);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

But, it's not giving me the expected result. It's storing all records for every group, But I want to store like - first 10 or fewer records as a group 1, second 10 or fewer records as group 2 and so on...

Thanks!!

Comment: is group 2 inserted or not...???

Comment: yes, group 2 inserted

Comment: could you tried like `foreach ($group[$i] as $key => $value) {` or `foreach ($group[$i] => $value) {`

Comment: if use `$group[$i]` then it's giving `Trying to get property 'user_id' of non-object` error.

Comment: chould you send  the array value `print_r($data);` after chunk...

Comment: `(2) [Array(10), {…}]0: (10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]1: {10: {…}, 11: {…}, 12: {…}, 13: {…}}`

Comment: Would you please visit to see screenshot - https://ibb.co/48cJZkD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope it Work...

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $tournamentid = $request->tournamentid;
    $data = TournamentPlayer::where('tournament_id', $tournamentid)->get()->chunk(10);

    // for ($i=1; $i <= count($data); $i++) { //removed
        foreach ($data as $i => $group) { // also assigned key for group count
            foreach ($group as $key => $value) {
                TournamentGroup::create([
                    'group' => $i+1, //changed
                    'tournament_id' => $tournamentid,
                    'user_id' => $value->user_id //player
                ]);
            }
        }

    //} //removed
}
```

Comment: getting `Property [user_id] does not exist on this collection instance` error